# What is a configmap cache?

Tags: kubernetes, timeout, kubernetes-pod, configmap

Anyone know what a `configmap cache` is by any chance?

Trying to debug a `failed to sync configmap cache` error here.

Comment: Please verify if the created configMap still exists in k8s via kubectl get cm -n your_namespace. Did you get this error from either journalctl -u kubelet or systemctl status kubelet?

Comment: The configMap definitely exists. 


I get the error when I run `kubectl get pods` or `kubectl get events`

Answer (score 3):

From the docs [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/#mounted-configmaps-are-updated-automatically)

> The kubelet uses its local cache for getting the current value of the
> ConfigMap from Kubernetes API Server. The type of the cache is configurable using the
> *ConfigMapAndSecretChangeDetectionStrategy* field in the
> KubeletConfiguration struct. A ConfigMap can be either propagated by
> watch (default), ttl-based, or simply redirecting all requests
> directly to the API server. As a result, the total delay from the
> moment when the ConfigMap is updated to the moment when new keys are
> projected to the Pod can be as long as the kubelet sync period + cache
> propagation delay, where the cache propagation delay depends on the
> chosen cache type (it equals to watch propagation delay, ttl of cache,
> or zero correspondingly)

`failed to sync configmap cache` could be because kubelet could not connect to Kubernetes API Server to get the updated configMap data. I would look into Kubelet logs using `journalctl -u kubelet`